# Swift Firebase getIDToken() crash with Google credential

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having some problem attempting to retrieve Firebase idToken with Google credential. But it works with email/pass.

Firebase setup

```
func configureSDK(){
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
 }
```

Google delegate

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    if let error = error {
        //error handling...

        return
    }

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else {

        //error handling
        return
    }

    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
        self.handleAuthAnswer(user: user, error: error)
    }
}
```

Sign-In handling

```
func handleAuthAnswer(user: User?, error: Error?){
    //error handling...
    //unwrapping User object
    //attempting to get token
    user.getIDToken(){ (idToken, error) in
        if error == nil, let token = idToken {
            self.idToken = token
        }else{
            //error handling
        }

    }
}
```

According to Firebase SDK Guide, I'm getting user object that is not nil, which means that user is signed in.
I see that user in the Firebase console.
The problem is that when I'm trying to get idToken, the app crashes. And there is no matter if I'm trying to sign-up, or to get token from Auth.auth().currentUser after next launch

Email/Pass sign-up and log in using the same method to get ID Token and it works without errors or crashes

Exception screenshots: 
[image: Trace]
[image: Thread]

EDIT: Pods

```
Using Firebase (4.13.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (4.2.0)
Using FirebaseAuth (4.6.1)
Using FirebaseCore (4.0.20)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.10)
Using GTMOAuth2 (1.1.6)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.15)
Using GoogleSignIn (4.1.2)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.3)
Using nanopb (0.3.8)
```

**SOLVED: Firebase pod was downgraded to 4.11.0. Works fine**

```
Installing Firebase 4.11.0 (was 4.13.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics 4.1.0 (was 4.2.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth 4.5.0 (was 4.6.1)
Installing FirebaseCore 4.0.18 (was 4.0.20)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.10)
Using GTMOAuth2 (1.1.6)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.15)
Using GoogleSignIn (4.1.2)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.3)
Using nanopb (0.3.8)
```

Comment: have you checked library version you are using?

Comment: It is the last one, I will add pods versions to my question, one moment

Comment: @MuhammadHannan interesting. Downgraded Firebase to 4.11.0 and is started to work...Your comment helped me to find the answer. Thanks

Comment: Good to know its solved, I have posted my answer as well, assisting other having similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the library version you are using. Whenever function, credentials, or API create any error, always check the version you are using.